# How to persist temporary NSManagedObjectContext without saving it to the parent context

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nscoding, uikit-state-preservation

I use CoreData to manage my application data model. I use child managed object context in my editing view controller so that I can ether save or discard the changes made by the user.

I create the child context as follows:

```
NSManagedObjectContext* mainMoc = <my main context>;
NSManagedObjectContext* editMoc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
editMoc.parentContext  = mainMoc;
```

If the user taps "done" button, I save changes as follows:

```
[editMoc save:&error]
```

If the user taps "cancel" I just discard the editMoc context.

Here is the question:
I use State Preservation and Restoration throughout my app, and I want to save the editMoc context with the changes for further restoration, when the app goes to background. I don't want to merge editMoc with the mainMoc, because the user did not decide yet whether to save or discard the changes.

I tried using the NSCoding protocol to serialize the editMoc, but the registered objects are not saved this way. 
I also tried to change the parentContext, but this throws an exception.

I believe there should be a nice way to accomplish the above task, as it is a common practice to use child contexts and state preservation.

My project runs on iOS 6.0 and above.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way internal to Core Data to save those objects.  What you can do, however, is ask that moc for all of its unsaved objects (`-updatedObjects`, `-insertedObjects`, `-deletedObjects`) and then iterate over them and save them to disk individually.  I would suggest saving them in an intermediary format like JSON or plists.